# "IOError: [Errno 71] Protocol error" when reading a file with python in a virtualbox debian machine

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I try to open and read a file in Python 2.7.3 which is running in a virtual machine:

Host: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Guest: Debian Wheezy 7.5

VM-Software: VirtualBox V4.3.30

In the Python console inside the VM, I enter the following:

```
>>> f = open("Testing/results.txt", "w+")
>>> f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 71] Protocol error
```

The file exists and is located in a shared folder. If I try to do the same on a file which is located on the file system of the VM, it works fine. Also opening the file with mode "r+" or "a+", it works but it doesn't get truncated. Truncating the file manually after opening in read mode is working and currently, I use that as a workaround. But maybe anybody here knows, why this error occurs?

Comment: My guess is that it's a permissions problem on the shared folder from the Host side.  Can you try making the shared folder more permissive from the Host?

Comment: What type of share are you using? Windows? SAMBA? VirtualBox Share?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files f = open("Testing/results.txt", "rb+") should work for you.

Comment: Where is the python script in relation to the file you are trying to open? Is it in the same directory?

Comment: 1. Have you try opening the file in C? Python 3?

Comment: 2. Most results online seem to indicate it is error 71 of the Linux system

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause of this error is a bug in the VirtualBox Linux Guest Additions, more specifically, one of its device drivers `vboxguest` (which communicates with the host) and `vboxsf` (which provides shared folder services on the guest on top of `vboxguest`).

Background: When using the Linux [`read(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call on VirtualBox shared files, specific conditions make the VirtualBox driver(s) fail with error `71 (EPROTO) – Protocol error` (see tickets below). The error originates in the Linux kernel space and propagates via the C library to applications (see [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)). In this case, the application happens to be the Python interpreter.

There is nothing wrong with the Python code or file permissions. The code just performs a legitimate sequence of operations which triggers the error.

Relevant VirtualBox tickets:

- [#2584 (vboxfs EPROTO error during file read)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2584)
- [#8463 (Protocol error when using strip over shared folders.)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8463)

According to ticket #8463, this bug (or a related one) was fixed in VirtualBox Linux Guest Additions 5.1.14 / 5.0.32 on January 17, 2017.